# my own on screen keyboard vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

i'm trying to make my own screen keyboard
but i have some problem with my code, it's look to long, please help me to make simple my code..

this my code :

```
Dim kotak As Integer

    Private Sub frmLogin_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtUsernamePassword_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtUsername.GotFocus, txtPassword.GotFocus
        If txtUsername.Focused = True Then
            kotak = 1
        ElseIf txtPassword.Focused = True Then
            kotak = 2
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnQ_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnQ.Click
        If kotak = 1 Then
            txtUsername.Text = txtUsername.Text & btnQ.Text
        ElseIf kotak = 2 Then
            txtPassword.Text = txtPassword.Text & btnQ.Text

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnW_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnW.Click
        If kotak = 1 Then
            txtUsername.Text = txtUsername.Text & btnW.Text
        ElseIf kotak = 2 Then
            txtPassword.Text = txtPassword.Text & btnW.Text

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnE_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnE.Click
        If kotak = 1 Then
            txtUsername.Text = txtUsername.Text & btnE.Text
        ElseIf kotak = 2 Then
            txtPassword.Text = txtPassword.Text & btnE.Text

        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a sub for it:

```
Private Sub AddLetter(ByVal letter As String)
    If kotak = 1 Then
            txtUsername.Text = txtUsername.Text & letter
        ElseIf kotak = 2 Then
            txtPassword.Text = txtPassword.Text & letter
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub btnQ_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnQ.Click
        AddLetter("Q")
End Sub

Private Sub btnW_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnW.Click
        AddLetter("W")
End Sub

Private Sub btnE_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnE.Click
        AddLetter("E")
End Sub
```

And so on...